# I need to ask some details but in a gender neutral way

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

I want to ask a landlord if there are any special rules for bachelors and bachelorettes who wish to rent his property.

Is there any way to use just one word instead of bachelors and bachelorettes?

*Off-topic: Is bachelorette really a word?*

OR completely change the sentence,

> Are there any special rules for unmarried....

I don't know how to end that sentence in the right way.

Answer (score 5):

The ordinary phrase would be **single people**.

"Bachelorettes" is a recent coining, often for young women on the party before one of them gets married, by symmetry with "bachelor party".  (Mostly US.)  This is likely to be misunderstood in your context.

- "**Unmarried people**" is perfectly good, but you might want to say "unmarried men or women" as a neutral, unambiguous phrase.
- **unmarried individual** for just one person of unspecified sex. "Can an unmarried individual rent the room?"

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term "individual renter".

I believe from a landlord's perspective, a bachelor, a bachelorette, a single woman, a single man, a divorced person, or a married person who rents a place due to work location makes not much difference in terms of setting up the tenancy rules.